# Odd error related to Stream being closed

Tags: java, input, stream, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am learning Java and I wrote a method to update a record in a file. The problem I am having is when I ask the user if they would like to look for another file my reader is closed or is unable to assign any input to it.

```
protected boolean Update() throws InputMismatchException
{
    RoomService Init =new RoomService();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            boolean ans= true;

         while(ans)
         {
            System.out.println("Please enter room number.");
            String id = input.next();
            Init.Update(id);
            System.out.println("Press Enter to Add more or no to exit");
            String choice = input.nextLine();// Skips this line 
                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                {
                    ans= false;
                }
                  else 
                  {
                      System.err.println("Wrong input");
                        throw new IOException();
                  }
         }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail=true;
        }
    return fail;
}
```

Wondering what exactly is blocking me from entering anything I also used `BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in))`

Thanks.

Edit:

Using Scanner Error is : java.util.NoSuchElementException

Using BufferedReader error is: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is anywhere else in your code you are using a `Scanner` wrapped around `System.in`, make sure you do not call `close()` on it. A `Scanner` itself has no resources that need to be closed, unless you want to close the underlying input source, which for a `Scanner` wrapped around `System.in`, you don't, because that prevents all future input.

Comment: I havent, because I use my View and Add functions and they all accept input when looped its just this update method. Not sure if something else is closing it maybe if I had a little more knowledge on Streams.

Comment: Try running the `Update` method on its own. If it no longer throws the exception, you know the problem is that some part of your code is closing `System.in`. Then put parts of the code back in one at a time to identify which part is doing that.

Comment: think this mite be the case but i am not sure, When you return froma  function within a try-catch resources, would it still close the resources ?

Comment: The [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (e.g., `try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) { ... }`) does close the resources when you exit the `try` block. That's the point of it. The [regular try statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) doesn't close anything on its own.

Comment: Found out what it was apparently i had a Suppress warning on it hence i didnt see the resource leak.